# Remove Leading zero in date

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have to enter the dates in the (mm/dd/yyyy) form. So, I will have something like 05/13/1999 when reporting this date how do I remove the zero so from the month. I want it to still be able to read double digit months like 11/12/1999

```
from functionax import disp_bday
name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
s = date = raw_input("Enter dob (mm/dd/yyyy): ")
x = month = int((s[0:1])             
year = s[6:10]
print disp_bday(name, month, year)
```

functionax is below

```
from datetime import date


def display_birthday_wishes(name, month, year):
    p = current_year = date.today().year
    current_age = (int(p)-int(year))
    if month == 1:
        month = 'Carnations'
    elif month == 2:
        month = 'Primroses'
    elif month == 3:
        month = 'Daffodils'
    elif month == 4:
        month = 'Sweet peas'
    elif month == 5:
        month = 'Hawthorn flowers'
    elif month == 6:
        month = 'Roses'
    elif month == 7:
        month = 'Water lilies'
    elif month == 8:
        month = 'Poppies'
    elif month == 9:
        month = 'Asters'
    elif month == 10:
        month = 'Calendulas'
    elif month == 11:
        month = 'Chrysanthemums'
    elif month == 12:
        month = 'Holly flowers'    

    return "Hi, " + name + ". You are " + str(current_age) +\
    " years old this year! Here's a bouquet of "+month+" for you!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a `-` before the item you want to strip 0 on.

```
datetime.strptime("05/13/1999", "%m/%d/%Y").strftime("%-m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like you want to use a [Regular Expression](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) for this:

```
import re

m = re.match(r'(\d{1,2})/(\d{1,2})/(\d{4})', date)
if m:
    print disp_bday(m.groups())
else:
    print "invalid input"
```

Take a look [here](https://regex101.com/r/oT4rC8/2) for more information on the used expression

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing parenthesis on line 4.

You could do:

```
from datetime import date

flowers = [
    'Carnations',
    'Primroses',
    'Daffodils',
    'Sweet peas',
    'Hawthorn flowers',
    'Roses',
    'Water lilies',
    'Poppies',
    'Asters',
    'Calendulas',
    'Chrysanthemums',
    'Holly flowers'
    ]

def display_birthday_wishes(name, month, year):
    p = date.today().year
    current_age = (int(p)-int(year))
    return "Hi, " + name + ". You are " + str(current_age) +\
    " years old this year! Here's a bouquet of "+ flowers[month-1] +" for you!"

name = raw_input("Enter name: ")
foo = raw_input("Enter dob (mm/dd/yyyy): ")
month, d, year = foo.split("/")
if month[0] == "0":
    month = int(month[1:])
print display_birthday_wishes(name, month, year)
```

Note that I had to revise the earlier example so as not to mention `date` (I just shortened that variable to `d`), otherwise it would have interfered with the `date` function.

Comment: I tried this and it works but it is returning "Here's a bouquet of 12 for you!" instead of the month flower it is just putting the month do you know why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the sate yourself, use the builtin `datetime` module

```
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("05/13/1999", "%m/%d/%Y")
>>> dt.month
5
>>> dt = datetime.strptime("11/12/1999", "%m/%d/%Y")
>>> dt.month
11
```

so, just replace the code

```
x = month = int((s[0:1])             
year = s[6:10]
```

to

```
dt = datetime.strptime(date , "%m/%d/%Y")
x = month = dt.month
year = dt.year
```

Answer (score 0):

**I haven't tried this in python2, but it works if you're using python3**

```
from datetime import date, datetime as dt

day, month, year = "05/13/1999".split("/")
old_date = date(int(year), int(day), int(month))
new_date = dt.strftime(old_date, "{0}/{1}/{2}".format(old_date.month, \
old_date.day, old_date.year))
```